# What are all the ways you can encounter an EmptyStatement in a JavaScript AST?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing a JS transpiler and need to know what I will encounter. I have handled almost every edge case except for the obscure `EmptyStatement`. One place I encounter it is here:

```
for (arrL = arr.length; arrL--; arr[arrL] *= baseIn);
```

The AST looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "Program",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "BlockStatement",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "AssignmentExpression",
          "left": {
            "type": "Identifier",
            "start": 4014,
            "end": 4018,
            "name": "arrL"
          },
          "right": {
            "type": "MemberExpression",
            "object": {
              "type": "Identifier",
              "start": 4021,
              "end": 4024,
              "name": "arr"
            },
            "property": {
              "type": "Identifier",
              "start": 4025,
              "end": 4031,
              "name": "length"
            },
            "computed": false
          },
          "operator": "="
        },
        {
          "type": "WhileStatement",
          "test": {
            "type": "Literal",
            "value": true,
            "raw": "true"
          },
          "body": {
            "type": "BlockStatement",
            "body": [
              {
                "type": "IfStatement",
                "test": {
                  "type": "UpdateExpression",
                  "argument": {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "start": 4033,
                    "end": 4037,
                    "name": "arrL"
                  },
                  "operator": "--",
                  "prefix": false
                },
                "consequent": {
                  "type": "BlockStatement",
                  "body": [
                    {
                      "type": "EmptyStatement",
                      "start": 4061,
                      "end": 4062
                    },
                    {
                      "type": "AssignmentExpression",
                      "left": {
                        "type": "MemberExpression",
                        "object": {
                          "type": "Identifier",
                          "start": 4041,
                          "end": 4044,
                          "name": "arr"
                        },
                        "property": {
                          "type": "Identifier",
                          "start": 4045,
                          "end": 4049,
                          "name": "arrL"
                        },
                        "computed": true
                      },
                      "right": {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "start": 4054,
                        "end": 4060,
                        "name": "baseIn"
                      },
                      "operator": "*="
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "alternate": {
                  "type": "BlockStatement",
                  "body": [
                    {
                      "type": "BreakStatement"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't even know what that `EmptyStatement` is referencing yet haha. What are the other cases where you run into `EmptyStatement`?

Comment: A good place to look for examples of `EmptyStatement` would be the tests for an existing AST based parser, for [example here on GitHub](https://github.com/eslint/espree/search?p=2&q=EmptyStatement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at that `for` statement, you'll see that it's body consists only of `;`. That's an empty statement. You'd get the same effect with, say,

```js
if (a--);
```

although many style guides discourage that. `{}` is a lot clearer, imho. That's an empty block, not an empty statement. `{;}` would be a block consisting only of an empty statement, which is also pretty rare, but you might find something like :

```js
if (debugging) {
    /* Commented out for now */ ;
}
```

So, what's an empty statement? It's a statement with nothing but a semicolon terminator. Empty, as it says.

It's interesting that the `for` statement has already been desugared, which might be confusing. But it's correct; `for(init; test; advance) body;` is semantically equivalent to

```
{
  init;
  while(true) {
    if (test) {
      body;
      advance;
    }
    else 
      break;
  }
}
```

Apparently, even though it desugared the `for` statement, it preserved the empty body. That might be in order to have a place to hang the line number, or it might just be that it was easier to leave it at that point in the parse. The curious transformation of an (implicit) `while (test) { ... }` into `while (true) { if (test) { ... } else break; }` is probably to simplify decomposition into basic blocks, or to enable a standard optimization which reorders the code. Just guesses, though.

Comment: So is every blank line with a semicolon an empty statement? Can you have multiple empty statements in a row?

Comment: @LancePollard: Only if you write them explicitly. A blank line by itself doesn't count, but `;;;;;` is a bunch of empty statements, whether or not there are newlines in between.

Comment: Most languages have empty statements. Exceptions are Python, where you actually have to write `pass`, and the Posix shell, where you sometimes see `:;` because empty statements aren't allowed.